# Error Message everytime I want to take the COUNT of a MySQL-QUERY (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here you can find a short sample of the database:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/olpnco5lmlg9vfz/wt_name.sql?dl=0

This is the part which is left only (after commenting all other parts) from the whole script:

```
<?PHP
$site = "page_id=3492";
$limit = "50";
$start          = (!isset($_REQUEST['start']) || $_REQUEST['start'] == '') ? 0 : $_REQUEST['start'];
include(connections.php);

$pdo = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $sHost_12, $db_12), $sUser_12, $sPass_12);

$sql_count      = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM `wt_name` WHERE `n_surname` LIKE 'A%' AND `n_file` = '4' AND `n_type` = 'NAME' ORDER BY `n_surname`, `n_givn` LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit;

$statement_count  = $pdo->prepare($sql_count);
$erg_count        = $statement_count->execute();
$result_count     = $statement_count->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$anzreihen        = $result_count[0]['COUNT'];
```

Everything works fine until the next-to-last line (`$result_count = $statement_count->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`). But everytime I want to put the count to variable `$anzreihen`, I get the error message:

> Error thrown
>   Call to a member function prepare() on null

The SQL-Query works fine and get's the right count to the `$result_count`-Array. I can also print the count on the page with:

```
echo $result_count[0]['COUNT'];
```

and it will be done without any error. Only when I want to give the count to another variable the error message comes up. I'm a bit angry, because I can't see any error in the script. The SQL-Query works fine and get's the correct result.

Comment: You don't need an ORDER BY on a query that COUNTs and it should be `$result_count['COUNT'];` OR `$result_count[0];`

Comment: Jay, when you closed this question as a "duplicate," are you *really sure* that it is?

Comment: Bagira, when you say *"put the count to variable $anzreihen"* ... you don't *show* us that.  Please submit a new posting to include the *complete* program that is failing, and show us exactly what line in that program is the place where the failure occurs.  I don't think that your posted code-snippet actually matches the subsequent commentary.

Comment: @Mike Robinson:
The rest of the script is commented by me and so unneeded to find the mistake. If I comment the link "$anzreihen        = $result_count[0]['COUNT'];" the script works fine. Even when I commented this line and do echo $result_count[0]['COUNT']; instead it works correct. Only when I want to put the COUNT to a variable I get the error message. So this line causes the error - and I can't see why.